# When smaller screen div's are not stretching

Tags: html, css, width

When i'm going to a smaller screen on my website, the header & footer are not 100% in width. Can someone explain me what's going on?

What i mean is that the body is being cut off...

[image]

Comment: the given link is not **responsive** may be that's why, for a quick solution you can set `min-width: 1200px;` to your `body`

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are trying to make your website responsive? Your `.container` class has a fixed width applied to it. Setting the `max-width` would make it wrap at smaller resolutions.

```
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1170px;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

I would recommend working with media queries, as mentioned [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/), so that you can apply styles at the widths where your design breaks.

Media queries will let you apply styles to specific widths. The styles will cascade all the way down until the min/max resolution, in relation to the device (viewport) width, equals to false and the condition set by the min/max resolution is no longer met.

An example would be the following

```
/* Mobile first CSS would come before
   the media queries below */ 

@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    .services .service {
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 25px;
    }
    .services .service + .service {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 720px) {
    .services .service {
        width: 50%;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1170px) {
    .services .service {
        width: 23%;
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    .services .service + .service {
        margin-left: 2.66%;
    }
}
```

However, I strongly urge you to look at the link in which all is explained in detail, so you can set the correct breakpoints and styles yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to make it responsive you can go with bootstrap framework it will be easy to make it responsive or just make it with putting the css class.

```
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1170px;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

and with header and footer make the width :auto; if possible so it should fit the window size.

Answer (score 1):

Your website is not mobile friendly but the answer of your question:

```
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1170px;
    //Add max-width
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: since its not responsive then adding `max-width: 100%;` will collapse the whole site and its really painful for anyone to browse it, instead of that giving a horizontal scroll is still useful.

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay That's right. I just answer the question and want to gives him some Ideas.